# Problem with function session_start() (works slowly)

Tags: php, apache, session, execution-time

I have a problem wtih `session_start()` on primary server. When I load page for the first time, it takes less than 1 second to complete request. If I'll wait for approximately 12-15 seconds and then reload page, time of loading will be the same. But when I'm trying to refresh page after, for example, 3 or 5 seconds after initial loading, time of the server's response equals 10 seconds.

I made some tests to define a bottleneck in my script and I found out, that function `session_start()` executes for 9.8 seconds. I'm using PEAR package HTTP_Session2. **Here is code snippet:**

```
HTTP_Session2::useCookies(SESSION_USE_COOKIE);
/* Next line was added to make logging of execution time possible. */
self::writeToFile('HTTP_useCookies(1) -> '.self::getWorkTime()); 
HTTP_Session2::start("SID");
self::writeToFile('HTTP_start(2) -> '.self::getWorkTime());
HTTP_Session2::setExpire(time() + SESSION_EXPIRE);
self::writeToFile('HTTP_setExpire(3) -> '.self::getWorkTime());
```

**Text of the logs:**

```
//First loading (13:34:35)
HTTP_useCookies(1) -> 0.00038
HTTP_start(2) -> 0.00077
HTTP_setExpire(3) -> 0.00090

// Second loading (13:34:39)(4 seconds later)
HTTP_useCookies(1) -> 0.00029
HTTP_start(2) -> <<<<<< 10.80752 >>>>>
HTTP_setExpire(3) -> <<<<<< 10.80780 >>>>>

//Third loading (13:34:56)
HTTP_useCookies(1) -> 0.00041
HTTP_start(2) -> 0.00071
HTTP_setExpire(3) -> 0.00083
```

So I found, that problem is in the `HTTP_Session2::start()` function. Code of the function `HTTP_Session2::start()`:

```
public function start($name = 'SessionID', $id = null)
{
  self::name($name);
  if (is_null(self::detectID())) {
    if ($id) {
      self::id($id);
    } else {
      self::id(uniqid(dechex(rand())));
    }
  }
  session_start();
  if (!isset($_SESSION['__HTTP_Session2_Info'])) {
    $_SESSION['__HTTP_Session2_Info'] = self::STARTED;
  } else {
    $_SESSION['__HTTP_Session2_Info'] = self::CONTINUED;
  }
}
```

I can't understand what is the cause of time delay. Probably, there are wrong Apache settings on the server. Or, maybe, there are some 'locks' on files with session information.

Maybe, someone has already encountered such problems and can help to solve it.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/13772074/168034

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The file containing the session's informations is locked during the time PHP serves a request.

So, if you have one PHP script (using a session) that's currently being executed, and the same user sends another request, the second request will wait until the first is finished.

Comment: I've just found, that there isone more request to the server, which starts after loading the whole page. So session file indeed was locked, but I couldn't define where. That's why I thought about apache settings. Thanks a lot, Pascal.

Comment: Thank you Pascal Martin, I ran into huge performance issue because of that. So if you have file1.php with `session_start(); sleep(10);` and you run a second script file2.php this one will also wait for that sleep from file1.