# Session start php no answer somitmes

Tags: php, session

I have a bug that I can not identify, in my php script I made a `session_start()` begin in my file.
but I do not understand why in some cases `session_start()` does not work and I could not return the server, but I have no errors from `PHP`.
I have read this link [session_start() takes VERY LONG TIME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772074/session-start-takes-very-long-time) and I have try to add `session_write_close()` but I still have the problem sometimes. 
I really do not look have you any ideas?

Maybe `session.gc_probability = 0` can help me ?

Code :

```
<?php
     session_start();
     echo "test";
?>
```

Comment: Define "does not work".  In what way does it fail?  Can you show sample code which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: No I have no error from php, in my `index.php` first line I have `session_start()` and somtimes `session_start()` don't work, I close my browser I re opened and it works @David

Comment: "don't work" isn't exactly a clarification of "does not work".  You have to actually describe the problem.  Nobody can answer "it doesn't work".

Comment: How you catch and decide that `session_start()` does not work? Missing session info or what?

Comment: If you paste a chunk of your code in here, we can help. Without seeing everything, we can't see what you are doing/possibly doing wrong.

Comment: Because after `session_start()` I have `echo "test` and Somtimes my `echo` never show @mitkosoft

Comment: Do you have error_reporting = on?

Comment: Yes I have `error_reporting = on` @Keyne Viana

Comment: But it should show you an error, try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Answer (score 0):

Try to put after start_session()

```
echo "SID1: ".SID."<br>session_id(): ".session_id()."<br>COOKIE: ".$_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"];
```