# How do I save PHP session data to a database instead of in the file system?

Tags: php, mysql, database, session

I have two websites, One is TLS and one is not, both are for the same client but I need the websites to share with each other (and only each other) common data for *users*, *orders*, *accounts* etc.

This would normally be done with `$_SESSION` data but I obviously these can't work across other sites, and I have found that I can store session data in a database (MySQL) rather than in the file system.

I have dug around and found [This useful guide](http://culttt.com/2013/02/04/how-to-save-php-sessions-to-a-database/) as well as this older but
[useful guide](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/session-handler.html). I also found [this guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/798978/Session-Storage-in-a-MySQL-Database) which has slightly more up to date MySQL.

I have written an interface class but it only partly works, it stores the session data in the database, but it doesn't retrieve it. I have also used the [suggested method from the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php).

**My MySQL** (as copied from first couple of the above links):

```
CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
  `id` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `access` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `data` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDb DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

> **Please Note:**
> Before I show you my interface class please know that the Db connetion uses my own custom made interface and that works perfectly, in itself.
>
> The `$sessionDBconnectionUrl` contains the Session Database connection details as I am keeping sessions on a seperate Database from the main website contents.

**My interface class** (as based on all the above links)

```
<?php
/***
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 ***/
class HafSessionHandler implements SessionHandler {
    private $database = null;
    
    public function __construct($sessionDBconnectionUrl){

        if(!empty($sessionDBconnectionUrl) && file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$sessionDBconnectionUrl)) {
            require_once "class.dataBase.php";
            // Instantiate new Database object
            $this->database = new Database($sessionDBconnectionUrl);
        }
        else {
            error_log("Session could not initialise class.");
        }
        
    }

    /**
     * Open
     */
    public function open($savepath, $id){
         $openRow = $this->database->getSelect("SELECT `data` FROM sessions WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1",$id);
    if($this->database->selectRowsFoundCounter() == 1){
        // Return True
        return $openRow['data'];
        }
    else {
        // Return False
        return ' ';
    }
    /**
     * Read
     */
    public function read($id)
    {
        // Set query
        $readRow = $this->database->getSelect('SELECT `data` FROM sessions WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1', $id,TRUE);
        if ($this->database->selectRowsFoundCounter() > 0) {
            return $readRow['data'];
        } else {
            error_log("could not read session id ".$id);
            return '';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Write
     */
    public function write($id, $data)
    {
        $access = time();
        // Set query
        $dataReplace[0] = $id;
        $dataReplace[1] = $access;
        $dataReplace[2] = $data;
        if ($this->database->noReturnQuery('REPLACE INTO sessions(id,access,`data`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', $dataReplace)) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Destroy
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        // Set query
        if ($this->database->noReturnQuery('DELETE * FROM sessions WHERE id = ? ', $id)) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {

            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    /**
     * Close
     */
    public function close(){
        // Close the database connection
        // If successful
        if($this->database->dbiLink->close){
            // Return True
            return true;
        }
        // Return False
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Garbage Collection
     */
    public function gc($max)
    {
        // Calculate what is to be deemed old
        $old = time() - $max;

        // Set query
        if ($this->database->noReturnQuery('DELETE * FROM sessions WHERE access < ?', $old)) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    
    public function __destruct()
    {
        $this->close();
    }

}
```

**My Test Page** (written from scratch!)

```
<?php
require "class.sessionHandler.inc.php";
$HSH = new HafSessionHandler("connection.session.dbxlink.php");
session_set_save_handler( $HSH, TRUE );
session_start();

print "<p>Hello this is an index page</p>";
$_SESSION['horses'] = "treesx3";
$_SESSION['tiespan'] = (int)$_SESSION['tiespan']+7;

print "<p>There should be some session data in the database now. <a href='index3.php'>link</a></p>";
var_dump($_SESSION);


exit;
```

**Issue:**

The test pages I run save the data to the database ok but they do not seem to retrieve the data,

I have error logging enabled and no PHP errors are reported. No critical MySQL errors are reported.

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: I guess your worst problems are cookie sharing betwen the domains (yes, client-side)...

Comment: why? can you explain a bit more?

Comment: The two sites will use a transfer page so all the visits to shopping site from the main site will be via a transfer page that setsup the session data transfer before passing the user on to their destination page.

Comment: See, the session key is stored in a cookie on the browser so the site knows it's the same visitor (cookies are sent in every request), however they are sandboxed by domain.
If `http://mywebsite.com/` tries to access your `http://google.com/` cookies, that is forbidden and a security flaw (someone could steal your gmail session).

Comment: That's why this isn't happening, both sites are referencing the session as stored in the DB. so that with an identifying marker passed from one site to another all the data can be retrieved in a *new* session cookie.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I have found over the course of several hours debugging that the referenced articles found on numerous Google searches as well as a significant subset of Stack Overflow answers such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11272422/3536236), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2950504/3536236) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30290579/3536236) all provide invalid or outdated information.

Things that can cause [critical] issues with saving session data to a database:

- While all the examples online state that you can "fill" the `session_set_save_handler`, none of them state that you must also set the `register_shutdown_function('session_write_close')` too ([reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php)).
- Several (older) guides refer to an outdated SQL Database structure, and should *not* be used. The database structure that you need for saving session data to the database is: `id`/`access`/`data`. That's it. no need for various extra timestamp columns as I've seen on a few "guides" and examples.

  - Several of the older guides also have outdated MySQL syntax such as `DELETE * FROM ...`
- The class [made in my question] must *[implement](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php)* the `SessionHandlerInterface` . I have seen guides (referenced above) that give the implementation of `sessionHandler` which is not a suitable interface. Perhaps previous versions of PHP had a slightly different method (probably <5.4).
- The session class methods *must* return the values set out by the PHP manual. Again, probably inherited from pre-5.4 PHP but two guides I read stated that `class->open` returns the row to be read, whereas the [PHP manual states](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) that it needs to return  `true` or `false` only.
- **This is the cause of my Original Issue**: I was using custom session names (actually id's as session names and session id's *are the same thing!*) as per [this very good StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419332/proper-session-hijacking-prevention-in-php) and this was generating a session name that was 128 characters long. As the session name is the sole key that is needed to be cracked to compromise a session and take over with a [session hijacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_hijacking_attack) then a longer name/id is a very good thing.

  - But, this caused an issue because ***MySQL was silently slicing the session id*** down to just 32 characters instead of 128, so it was never able to find the session data in the database. This was a completely silent issue (maybe due to my database connection class not throwing warnings of such things). But this is the one to watch out for. If you have any issues with retrieving sessions from a database first check is that the *full* session id can be stored in the field provided.

So with all that out of the way there are some extra details to add as well:

The PHP manual page (linked above) shows an unsuitable pile of lines for a class object:

> ```
> $handler = new MySessionHandler();
> session_set_save_handler($handler, true);
> session_start();
> ```

Whereas it works just as well if you put this in the class constructor:

```
class MySessionHandler implements SessionHandlerInterface {

    private $database = null;

public function __construct(){

    $this->database = new Database(whatever);

    // Set handler to overide SESSION
    session_set_save_handler(
        array($this, "open"),
        array($this, "close"),
        array($this, "read"),
        array($this, "write"),
        array($this, "destroy"),
        array($this, "gc")
        );
    register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');
    session_start();
    }
...
}
```

*This* means that to then start a session on your output page all you need is:

```
<?php
require "path/to/sessionhandler.class.php"; 
new MySessionHandler();

//Bang session has been setup and started and works
```

---

For reference the complete Session communication class is as follows, this works with PHP 5.6 (and probably 7 but not tested on 7 yet)

```
<?php
/***
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 ***/
class MySessionHandler implements SessionHandlerInterface {
    private $database = null;

    public function __construct($sessionDBconnectionUrl){
        /***
         * Just setting up my own database connection. Use yours as you need.
         ***/ 

            require_once "class.database.include.php";
            $this->database = new DatabaseObject($sessionDBconnectionUrl);

        // Set handler to overide SESSION
        session_set_save_handler(
            array($this, "open"),
            array($this, "close"),
            array($this, "read"),
            array($this, "write"),
            array($this, "destroy"),
            array($this, "gc")
        );
        register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');
        session_start();
    }

    /**
     * Open
     */
    public function open($savepath, $id){
        // If successful
        $this->database->getSelect("SELECT `data` FROM sessions WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1",$id,TRUE);
        if($this->database->selectRowsFoundCounter() == 1){
            // Return True
            return true;
        }
        // Return False
        return false;
    }
    /**
     * Read
     */
    public function read($id)
    {
        // Set query
        $readRow = $this->database->getSelect('SELECT `data` FROM sessions WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1', $id,TRUE);
        if ($this->database->selectRowsFoundCounter() > 0) {
            return $readRow['data'];
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Write
     */
    public function write($id, $data)
    {
        // Create time stamp
        $access = time();

        // Set query
        $dataReplace[0] = $id;
        $dataReplace[1] = $access;
        $dataReplace[2] = $data;
        if ($this->database->noReturnQuery('REPLACE INTO sessions(id,access,`data`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', $dataReplace)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Destroy
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        // Set query
        if ($this->database->noReturnQuery('DELETE FROM sessions WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1', $id)) {
            return true;
        } else {

            return false;
        }
    }
    /**
     * Close
     */
    public function close(){
        // Close the database connection
        if($this->database->dbiLink->close){
            // Return True
            return true;
        }
        // Return False
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Garbage Collection
     */
    public function gc($max)
    {
        // Calculate what is to be deemed old
        $old = time() - $max;

        if ($this->database->noReturnQuery('DELETE FROM sessions WHERE access < ?', $old)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        $this->close();
    }

}
```

Usage: As shown just above the class code text.

Comment: FYI: the open() does not use the $savepath parameter

Comment: When is the session initially added to the database? Your `open` function should really only check to see if there's a valid connection to the database. Right now it would appear it is checking to see if there is a valid session already in the database -- if this was a new session being created, I doubt it would ever return `true`.

Comment: @paul look at original interface implementation:  public function open($savePath, $sessionName)
    {
        $this->savePath = $savePath;
        if (!is_dir($this->savePath)) {
            mkdir($this->savePath, 0777);
        }

        return true;
    }

Comment: @Martin, session variable set to empty on second page. I am setting session values in a page and those values are storing to the database, but when I am retrieving it on another page it is logging me out and setting the session variable to an empty array, do you know why?

Comment: @Neeraj Ask a new question outlining what you have tried to do yourself and why it failed.  Cheers

Comment: you may want to protect your open callback against timing attacks

Comment: it is giving me an error `Warning: session_start(): Failed to initialize storage module: user (path: C:\xampp\tmp)` in session.php on line 26

Comment: ok, it seems this is due to the `open()` function returns false when there are no sessions with a corresponding id, so instead of it returning false it should return `$this->write($id,'')` which will create a new session when there is no session with the corresponding id.

Comment: @ZOLDIK which PHP version is it?

Comment: @Martin it is 7.3.9, and actually I was wrong, doing that will create an unused session when there is no session with a corresponding id(2 sessions for one user, one is unused), it worked normally when I made the `open()` function just return true; I don't exactly know what is the purpose of the function is. let me know if I'm doing it wrong

Comment: @ZOLDIK The `open` class is simply to tell PHP core that it can continue to try and read/write from the session because a valid session has been found, this is why it returns a boolean instead of the session data.