# passing php sessions from subdomains working on subdomain but not ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, apache

## Problem

I have a page which is generated **entirely** through *JavaScript*. I grab the content by requesting data from a *PHP* script on a subdomain (`ajx.example.com)`, then return it in *JSON* format.

One of the requirements for this particular page is to be "editable" if a user is logged in (which is one of the keys in the *JSON*, `"isEditable":true`). If I visit the request page (on the subdomain) directly, and the user is logged in on (on the main domain), `isEditable` is **always** `true`. However, if I request it via an Ajax request, it's always `false`.

These subdomains are done through a **VirtualHost** on **MAMP**, and all point to the same directory. 
`www.example.com` is in `htdocs/example`,
`ajx.example.com` is in `htdocs/example/ajax`, and 
`v1.examplecdn.com` is in `htdocs/example/cdn`.

---

## Code

Here is the **init** page (`www.example.com/app/init.php`:

```
ini_set("session.cookie_domain", ".example.com"); // make sure all sessions are available on all subdomains
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();

// I include the user class here
```

Here is the **request** page (`ajx.example.com/request.php`):

```
require_once "../app/init.php"; // (/htdocs/example/app/init.php)
header("Content-type: application/json;charset=utf-8", false);
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example.com", false);

$user = new User();
$editable = false;

if($user->loggedIn()){ // check if user is logged in (this is stored in a session on .example.com
    $editable = true;
}
die(json_encode(array("isEditable" => $editable)));
```

And here is the request **Ajax** (`v1.examplecdn.com/request.js`):

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
ajax({
    url: "//ajx.example.com/request.php", // (/htdocs/example/ajax/request.php)
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(res){
        if(res.isEditable){
            console.log("editable"); // this doesn't come through as isEditable is false.
        }
    }
});
```

---

## Request

If anyone can point me into the direction of how to make it so that those *PHP Sessions* can be accessed via those subdomains, it would be **greatly** appreciated!
Cheers.

Comment: Where is your `ajax` function setting the parameter necessary for passing along cookies with cross-domain requests?

Comment: @CBroe Honestly, I didn't know that was a requirement. How would I do that? :)

Comment: http://promincproductions.com/blog/cross-domain-ajax-request-cookies-cors/

Answer (score 0):

You are right until this setting - 
ini_set("session.cookie_domain", ".example.com"); // make sure all sessions are available on all subdomains

But as you have different domains on different VM's, they cannot share the session, as each of the VM will create its own copy of new session, to allow session sharing you need to save sessions either in DB or in cache service , like memcache, redis etc.

saving sessions in db table has been explained here

[How do I save session data to a database instead of in the file system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753513/how-do-i-save-session-data-to-a-database-instead-of-in-the-file-system?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: I don’t know where you are getting “different VM's” from, the question only mentioned VirtualHosts.