# How to store session for lifetime in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Well, I am going straight, How can i store session into database? I have tried and stored session into database but It will delete automatically from db because of codeigniter database garbage collector.

I don't know how to keep all the sessions? I don't want to delete any session from database. I don't want to delete session until database user delete the row.

Moreover, I want to develop user can log out from all the sessions.

Please share your thoughts. thanks.

Comment: Check please documentation - https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#session-drivers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I save PHP session data to a database instead of in the file system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753513/how-do-i-save-php-session-data-to-a-database-instead-of-in-the-file-system)

Answer (score 1):

Set the session expiration value of `sess_expiration` in the config to 0 if you don't want it to timeout unless the browser is closed, or set it to an crazy amount like 5 years.

> **sess_expiration:** The number of seconds you would like the session to last. If you would like a non-expiring session (until browser is closed) set the value to zero: 0

The config file is found at: **application/config/config.php**

You can also disable automatic session regeneration by setting `sess_time_to_update` to 0.

Reference: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#session-preferences

Comment: I added this but session still removed from database. Moreover i have put 0 in sess_expiration also, but still its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `$config['sess_expiration'] = 0` for lifetime.

Comment: I added this but session still removed from database. Moreover i have put 0 in sess_expiration also, but still its not working.